# is_product_category('Services') not working

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, conditional-tags

I'd like to hide the "add to cart" & price for WooCommerce products in the 'Services' category.

I've tried the following code in my child theme's functions.php, but https://pureblissmoonhealer.com/product-category/services/ still displays "add to cart" & price.

Help appreciated.

```
function insight_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in() {   
    if (! is_user_logged_in()) {
        if (is_product_category('Services')) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );   
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'insight_print_register_to_see', 31 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'insight_print_register_to_see', 11 );
        }
    }
}

function insight_print_register_to_see() {
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">' . __('Register to see prices', 'theme_name') . '</a>';
}

add_action( 'init', 'insight_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in' );
```

Comment: The `init` hook is too early for `is_product_category()`. Try `wp` or a later hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to hide `add to cart` & `price` for WooCommerce products in the 'Services' category.

```
// Specific product category archive and shop pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'hide_loop_product_prices', 1 );
function hide_loop_product_prices(){
    global $product;
    if (! is_user_logged_in()) {

        if(  is_product_category('services') || has_term( 'services', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
            // Hide prices
            remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
            // Hide add-to-cart button
            remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );

            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'insight_print_register_to_see', 31 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'insight_print_register_to_see', 99 );
       }
       else
       {
            add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
            add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );

            remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'insight_print_register_to_see', 31);
remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','insight_print_register_to_see', 99 );
       }
    }
}

// Single product pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'hide_single_product_prices', 1 );
function hide_single_product_prices(){
    global $product;
    if (! is_user_logged_in()) {
        if(is_product_category('services') || has_term( 'services', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ):

            // Hide prices
            remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
            // Hide add-to-cart button, quantity buttons (and attributes dorpdowns for variable products)
            if( ! $product->is_type('variable') ){
                remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
            } else {
                remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
            }
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'insight_print_register_to_see', 31 );

        endif;
    }
}

function insight_print_register_to_see() {
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">' . __('Login/Register to see Price', 'theme_name') . '</a>';
}
```

i have tested this code and working fine for me. let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks Chetan. I've added this code to the child theme `functions.php`, replacing the existing code, but the prices remain @ [the category in question](https://pureblissmoonhealer.com/product-category/services/).

Comment: Still seeking help please.

Comment: i have check your website it is working fine. https://prnt.sc/pwo6th please open your website in incognito window without login

Comment: Did you check ? here is other category which show price and add to cart https://prnt.sc/pwoysh. and here is service category which price and add to cart button hidden https://prnt.sc/pwoyyj. means it is working fine.

Comment: The [product page](https://pureblissmoonhealer.com/product/distant-healing-1-session-is-1-hour/) still has the price unfortunately.

Comment: Hello Chetan ? Cheers.

Comment: Please check after cleaning  LiteSpeed Cache. I have checked by my end and it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks Chetan. I've emptied the Litespeed Cache, logged out, but the [product page](https://pureblissmoonhealer.com/product/distant-healing-1-session-is-1-hour/) still displays the price. I've recopied and pasted your code into the child theme's functions.php, and cPanel editor says no change were detected, so I'm using the right code.

Comment: did you create Woocommerce single product page with Elementor ?

Comment: Thanks Chetan, we inherited this site from the previous developer, and yes the single product page is controlled by an Elementor template. The Elementor components are `Price` & `Button`. Cheers.

Comment: That is why code does not applied on product detail page components. because it is not woocommerce default page template. this code works perfectly on woocommerce template i have checked.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this method will helpful for you.Resource form https://www.skyverge.com/blog/checking-woocommerce-cart-contains-product-category/

```
function insight_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in() {
    $cat_check = false;
    if (! is_user_logged_in()) {
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $product = $cart_item['data'];
            if ( has_term( 'Services', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
                $cat_check = true;
                break;
            }
        }  
        if ( $cat_check ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );   
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'insight_print_register_to_see', 31 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'insight_print_register_to_see', 11 );
        }   
    }
}

function insight_print_register_to_see() {
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">' . __('Register to see prices',     'theme_name') . '</a>';
}

add_action( 'init', 'insight_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does that need a product to be in the cart first? We need the price and add to cart to be hidden before they do anything, including adding to cart.

Comment: Have you used is_category() function instead of is_product_category()

Comment: I definitely used `is_product_category`

Comment: Still seeking help please.